# write SQL insert, update and delete commands in a batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-delete

Can I write SQL insert, update and delete commands in a batch file? If I can do so can someone give me an example please.

Answer (score 1):

write the sql code and save as .sql extension. (code.sql)
then call it from a batch file, 
eg 
`@echo off
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i code.sql`

Save this as a *.bat file.

Comment: Can you please explain me how can I get the InstanceName here?

Comment: it is your Database instance name eg :- 'database1'

Comment: Thanks. But how do you know whether your sql commands have worked properly?